# what is the proper way for testing create action in rails RESTfull controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4.2, rspec3, ruby-2.1

I have a users_controller.rb file in which the create action is defined as:-

```
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  if current_user.g_admin?
    @user.role = 'c_admin'
  elsif current_user.c_admin?
    @user.role = 'c_user'
  end
  @user.admin_provisioned = true
  authorize @user
  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save
      format.html { redirect_to authenticated_root_url, notice: 'User was successfully created and email has been sent.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Now, I would like to write test for this method reflecting all the behaviour in this method. I'm completely new to testing, so detailed and standard way for writing test will be accepted as answer. The version to rspec is 3.4. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

So the following way you could test this with rspec and capybara. For the fill in part you have to use the input elements that you have on your page.

```
describe "let an guest create a user account" do
  fill_in :user_object, with: "value"

  click_button "Save User"

  expect(page).to have_content("User was successfully created and email has been sent.")
end


describe "let an guest try to create an account with invalid data" do
  fill_in :user_object, with: "invalid value"

  click_button "Save User"

  expect(page).to_not have_content("User was successfully created and email has been sent.")
  expect(page).to have_content("content from the :new page")
end
```